# Problemas al Insertar datos a una tabla con varias claves foraneas

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, estoy intentando insertar datos en todas las tablas de mi base de datos, en especial la de alumno que depende de tres claves foraneas ya ya obtuve al ejecutar los querys anteriores. Dejare todos los querys, pero me gustaria que detallaran el de alumnos que es el cual me produce el error, muchas gracias.

Aquí el error que me da al ejecutar el query:
[image: Error del query]

```
            //Registro de representantes        
$registroRepresentante = "insert into representantes (tipoCedulaRepresentante, cedulaRepresentante, primerApellidoRepresentante, segundoApellidoRepresentante, primerNombreRepresentante, segundoNombreRepresentante, edadRepresentante, direccionRepresentante, codigoTelefonoRepresentante, telefonoRepresentante, correoRepresentante, direccionTrabajoRepresentante, codigoTelefonoTrabajoRepresentante, telefonoTrabajoRepresentante, direccionEmergencia, fk_parentesco, fk_profesion) values (
    '$_POST[tipoCedulaRepresentante]','$_POST[cedulaRepresentante]','$_POST[primerApellidoRepresentante]',
    '$_POST[segundoApellidoRepresentante]','$_POST[primerNombreRepresentante]','$_POST[segundoNombreRepresentante]',
    $_POST[edadRepresentante],'$_POST[direccionRepresentante]','$_POST[codigoTelefonoRepresentante]',
    '$_POST[telefonoRepresentante]','$_POST[correoRepresentante]','$_POST[direccionTrabajoRepresentante]',
    '$_POST[codigoTelefonoTrabajoRepresentante]','$_POST[telefonoTrabajoRepresentante]','$_POST[direccionEmergencia]',
    '$_POST[parentescoRepresentante]','$_POST[profesionRepresentante]')";

    $registrarRepresentante = mysqli_query($conexion,$registroRepresentante) or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    echo "ingresaron datos representantes";

    //Consulta del ultimo representante ingresado para optener su clave foranea
$consultarRepresentante = mysqli_query($conexion, "select max(id_representante) from representantes")  or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    $registros = mysqli_fetch_array($consultarRepresentante);
    echo $registros[0]."<br>";
    $foraneaRepresentante = '$registro[0]';


    //Registro de los padres
$registroPadres =  "insert into padres (tipoCedulaPadre, cedulaPadre, primerApellidoPadre, segundoApellidoPadre, primerNombrePadre, segundoNombrePadre, direccionPadre, codigoTelefonoPadre, telefonoPadre) values ('$_POST[tipoCedulaPadre]','$_POST[cedulaPadres]',
    '$_POST[primerApellidoPadres]','$_POST[segundoApellidoPadres]','$_POST[primerNombrePadres]','$_POST[segundoNombrePadres]',
    '$_POST[direccionPadres]','$_POST[codigoTelefonoPadres]','$_POST[telefonoPadres]') ";

    $registrarPadres = mysqli_query($conexion,$registroPadres) or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    echo "ingresaron datos padres";

    //Consulta del ultimo padre ingresado para optener su clave foranea
$consultarPadre = mysqli_query($conexion, "select max(id_padre) from padres")  or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    $registros = mysqli_fetch_array($consultarPadre);
    echo $registros[0]."<br>";
    $foraneaPadre = '$registro[0]';


    //Registro del estatus de los alumnos
$registroEstatusAlumno = "insert into estatusalumno (estadoAlumno, institutoProcedencia, asignaturaQueCursa, fechaInscripcion) values (
    '$_POST[estadoAlumno]','$_POST[institutoProcedencia]','$_POST[asignaturaCursa]','$fechaActual')";

    $registrarEstatusAlumno = mysqli_query($conexion,$registroEstatusAlumno) or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    echo "ingresaron datos de estatus";

    //Consulta del ultimo estatus ingresado para optener su clave foranea
$consultarEstatus = mysqli_query($conexion,"select max(id_estatus) from estatusalumno") or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    $registros = mysqli_fetch_array($consultarEstatus);
    echo $registros[0]."<br>";
    $foraneaEstatus = '$registro[0]';


    //Registro del estatus de los alumnos
$registroAlumno = "insert into alumnos (tipoCedulaAlumno, cedulaAlumno, primerApellidoAlumno, segundoApellidoAlumno, primerNombreAlumno, segundoNombreAlumno, fechaNacimientoAlumno, edadAlumno, direccionAlumno, codigoTelefonoAlumno, telefonoAlumno, correoAlumno, fk_representante, fk_padre, fk_estatusalumno) values ('$_POST[tipoCedulaAlumno]','$_POST[cedulaAlumno]','$_POST[primerApellidoAlumno]','$_POST[segundoApellidoAlumno]','$_POST[primerNombreAlumno]','$_POST[segundoNombreAlumno]','$_POST[fechaNacimientoAlumno]',$edadac,'$_POST[direccionAlumno]','$_POST[codigoTelefonoAlumno]','$_POST[telefonoAlumno]','$_POST[correoAlumno]', 
    '$foraneaRepresentante','$foraneaPadre','$foraneaEstatus')";

    $registrarAlumnos = mysqli_query($conexion,$registroAlumno) or die ("Problemas en el query: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    echo "ingresaron datos alumnos";

    //Consulta del ultimo alumno ingresado para optener su clave foranea
$consultarAlumno = mysqli_query($conexion,"select max(id_alumno) from alumnos") or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    $registros = mysqli_fetch_array($consultarAlumno);
    echo $registro[0]."<br>";
    $foraneaAlumno = '$registro[0]';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay que tener cuidado cuando creas una `FK` entre tablas que ya contienen datos, es muy probable que al menos un registro no cumpla la restricción, y por tanto `MySQL` disparará el error.

Otro punto tener en cuenta, rechazará cualquier operación `INSERT` o `UPDATE` que intente crear un valor de clave externa en una tabla secundaria si no hay un valor de clave candidata coincidente en la tabla principal.

Primero comprobaría, lo que te he mencionado, para encontrar el fallo, sino podrías subir algún `diagrama E-R` de la `base de datos`.

Luego también modificaría los `$_POST[$tu_variable]`, añadiría `''` entre los `[]`,  quedaría así `$_POST['$tu_variable']`

Comment: Gracias, ya subo el diagrama. Otra pregunta que diferencia hay entre colocar las comillas dentro de los corchetes a colocarlos fuera?

Comment: Las que estas añadiendo fuera no tienen nada que ver con tu variable `$_POST` , quedaria asi ,`'$_POST['tu_variable']', '$_POST['tu_variable']'`

Comment: Eso le estaba explicando ayer a @shadowmors de las comillas pero no era posible... pero si lo pones ahora como en el comentario le saldrá error... tiene que concatenar lo bien.. tipo: `$xxx = '..... " '.$_POST['xxx'].' " .....';` ademas las variables: `$foraneaPadre = '$registro[0]';` tampoco le va a funcionar... tiene que aprender como y cuando se usan doble- y simple comillas y como concatenar bien y sobre todo usar sentencias preparadas

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, y ya entendí mi falla con respecto a ayer y las comillas. De verdad disculpa por porfiarle lo que me estaba diciendo.

Comment: De nada, aqui te dejo el manual como explican correctamente como usar comillas simples o dobles, ofrecen ejemplos claros @shadowmors, un saludo y suerte. http://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Mariano no di como positiva la repuesta ya que ninguno de los comentarios dio respuesta a la misma, aldanux me ayudo a ver otro error que tenia, mas no respondió la pregunta, ¿por que? 1) por que para hacer los insert relacionados debía obtener las claves primarias o IDS de cada query registrado, para eso debía usar la función mysqli_insert_id que me arroja como valor la id del ultimo query que se uso y esta puede usarla como referencia para las claves foráneas, muchas gracias.

Comment: @shadowmors ok, está perfecto, y eliminé mi comentario (había malinterpretado tus "gracias", pero estoy seguro que cuando comentas lo que falta en la respuesta le da la chance a otros a que entiendan qué falta y ver si pueden contestarlo). Quizás sea recomendable editar la pregunta aclarando qué falta luego de estas respuestas